# Compile code fully in memory with javax.tools.JavaCompiler

Tags: java, compilation, javac, java-compiler-api

I'm using the JavaCompiler from the javax.tools package (JDK 1.7) to compile some stuff on the fly, like this:

```
compiler.run(null, null, "-cp", paths, "path/to/my/file.java");
```

It works but I would like to do it all in memory (e.g. pass a string with the code, not the source file, and get the byte code back not a .class file). I found that extending the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` parameters is no use since it's probably just the same as in the console. Do you know a way to make the run method work like this? Or do you know a confirmed way to do this with the `getTask()` method? (extending the FileManager looks easy but isn't that easy :)

Comment: There is a bit more in a class file than just byte code. A class file also holds method and field signatures etc. The byte codes are just the method bodies.

Comment: I have a library to do this.  You give it a String and it returns the complied class which you can call.  https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Runtime-Compiler you can add the class/method as a template to compile just a snippet of code and if that class implements a well know interface you can call it on an instance of the class.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I've run the above code in Mac OS Java 7. None of them works. So i wrote one
https://github.com/trung/InMemoryJavaCompiler

```java
StringBuilder source = new StringBuilder()
    .append("package org.mdkt;\n")
    .append("public class HelloClass {\n")
    .append("   public String hello() { return \"hello\"; }")
    .append("}");

Class<?> helloClass = InMemoryJavaCompiler.compile("org.mdkt.HelloClass", source.toString());
```

Comment: I hope i'm not breaking some ettiquete but this answer is now the best answer (separate module which directly returns a compiled & loaded class without producing a .class file on disk). It's also almost the same with the solution i linked to: http://www.javablogging.com/dynamic-in-memory-compilation/ and the solution i wrote myself based on that link.

Comment: @Teo That exactly what my answer did. It only writes to disk if you are debug mode so you can step into the code when debugging. By default it works entirely in memory.  BTW It has been in production for years with many users so it is perhaps the best tested solution.

Comment: StringBuffer was replaced by StringBuilder ten years ago, I suggest you avoid using it, ever.

Comment: @Peter i suggested an edit, there's no reason to use the slower StringBuffer above (actually i think they are both still valid, but StringBuffer is synchronized and StringBuilder not (thus faster)). About your answer, i don't really remember why i didn't accept it as THE answer, it was 2 years ago, but maybe one reason was the availability of the source code wasn't obvious - i see you updated your answer with that link just recently. Also erolagnab said "none of them works" - erolagnab (if you have time) did you try to run Peter's code and didn't work on Mac OS? Was there an error?

Comment: @Teo there have been multiple releases and as I say it has been used since 2008. In the last few years by multiple companies.  The link to very old code is on the first line.  Perhaps this doesn't work now, it is 7 years old.

Comment: @Peter because you gave your answer first (and because this question seems to be popular) i'll investigate both 'codes' and will try to decide again - but until then, just by looking at the snippets, i would prefer the current answer - while yours seems more 'full of features' i have the feeling i prefer the current one because of its ease of use & static approach (more obvious for newcomers).

Comment: @Teo `CompilerUtils.CACHED_COMPILER` is a static field. If the old version didn't work, I could understand that, but your reasons for saying it's better don't make sense to me.

Comment: @Peter yes but in my opinion it's more obvious in this answer with InMemoryJavaCompiler.compile(...) unlike the small logic that you are using (static cached compiler vs constructed compiler) which although not important still adds to the size of the answer. But i see you edited your answer anyway :) I'd like to investigate & actually run both codes so that simplicity isn't my only argument but right now it is :S I'll come back with a comment when i'm done.

Comment: @Teo On the other hand if it doesn't work, please let me know and I will issue a bug for this use case.

Comment: @Teo given dynamic compilation in Java is an advanced topic, I had assumed a certain level of understand on how Java works or how the code could be changed to suit your needs.

Comment: @Peter: tried to run your answer by pasting your source code in my project and found you have some extra dependencies there (for loggers, annotations, etc.). This made me decide i don't want to test it anymore, i don't want to have to mavenize or add some dependencies to my project that aren't essential to my question. The current answer (which worked just by pasting) doesn't have such 'clutter' & was obvious enough at the time it was posted to convince me to accept it.  I realize maybe this is a bit unfair to your answer (which i upvoted btw) since you obviously know what you're talking about

Comment: But since i see a strong 'didactic' trait for this question i think any answer being feature-filled or proven in production (or given earlier) is less powerful than a straight answer that works out of the box. If you think this is wrong feel free to address moderators or whatever the procedure is, but considering my state of mind when i asked this question (which is probably similar to other people 'frustrated' by this problem) i still prefer the current answer.

Comment: @Teo I can understand not wanting to mavenise your project but when you get sick of building other projects code and managing your dependencies you might find using a build tool will be easier in the long run. esp if you work in a larger organisation.

Comment: Once I have that class, how can I run it?

Answer (score 33):

I think this here might be of help it basically shows how to compile Java source from memory (the string is located in the class).

It uses the `PrinterWriter` and `StringWriter` to write the source to a `String`/in memory and then uses the `JavaCompiler` class (since JDK 6) to compile and run the program:

```
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;
import javax.tools.DiagnosticCollector;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler.CompilationTask;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.SimpleJavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class CompileSourceInMemory {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer);
    out.println("public class HelloWorld {");
    out.println("  public static void main(String args[]) {");
    out.println("    System.out.println(\"This is in another java file\");");    
    out.println("  }");
    out.println("}");
    out.close();
    JavaFileObject file = new JavaSourceFromString("HelloWorld", writer.toString());

    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = Arrays.asList(file);
    CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, null, diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits);

    boolean success = task.call();
    for (Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) {
      System.out.println(diagnostic.getCode());
      System.out.println(diagnostic.getKind());
      System.out.println(diagnostic.getPosition());
      System.out.println(diagnostic.getStartPosition());
      System.out.println(diagnostic.getEndPosition());
      System.out.println(diagnostic.getSource());
      System.out.println(diagnostic.getMessage(null));

    }
    System.out.println("Success: " + success);

    if (success) {
      try {

          URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { new File("").toURI().toURL() });
          Class.forName("HelloWorld", true, classLoader).getDeclaredMethod("main", new Class[] { String[].class }).invoke(null, new Object[] { null });

      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Class not found: " + e);
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        System.err.println("No such method: " + e);
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        System.err.println("Illegal access: " + e);
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        System.err.println("Invocation target: " + e);
      }
    }
  }
}

class JavaSourceFromString extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
  final String code;

  JavaSourceFromString(String name, String code) {
    super(URI.create("string:///" + name.replace('.','/') + Kind.SOURCE.extension),Kind.SOURCE);
    this.code = code;
  }

  @Override
  public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
    return code;
  }
}
```

If you have a look at the reference link you will find a few more other examples too

**Reference:**

- [Compiling from Memory](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/CompilingfromMemory.htm)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem completely! It still generates a class file and tries to load it.

Comment: @david kroukamp i run this code but it gives me classnotfound exception.i asked it on os.but no answers yet .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173294/compiling-fully-in-memory-with-javax-tools-javacompiler/12173346#12173346

Comment: @Fast Snail: Fixed the code. The only relevant changes (Ignoring imports.) are in the "try" block.

Comment: @Dawnkeeper: Found an example that *does* do everything purely in memory. You have to copy a few classes, though, it's not one convenient copy&paste. But it's worth the 3 minutes. http://javapracs.blogspot.de/2011/06/dynamic-in-memory-compilation-using.html

Comment: @DreamspacePresident Thanks for digging this up =)

Comment: @Dawnkeeper I added an answer to this post with the working compiler, reduced by about 100 lines. By now I also have a multiple-class version of this, but I hadn't put it here yet, but it's not that hard to make the changes.

Answer (score 12):

This is a class that compiles *entirely* in memory.

I've taken (almost) the entirety of this from http://javapracs.blogspot.de/2011/06/dynamic-in-memory-compilation-using.html by Rekha Kumari (June 2011). Though this version is more than 100 lines shorter and has considerably more features (but no docs:P).

It can compile multiple classes at once, which is the only way to compile classes that depend on each other. If you wonder about the class "CompilerFeedback": I was working on a tiny Java [IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJvrE.png) for coding-games where I needed that. I'm including it here because I assume that you want to *do* something with this compiler, and the predigestion might help with that. (I realize that some of the code in the CompilerFeedback class is complete crap. It was recycled from a years old attempt.

There's also a utility method, not needed for compilation, that derives the full class name from a class' source code (incl. package name, if it's provided). Very useful for calling the compiler, which does need this information.

DEMO CLASS:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final InMemoryCompiler.IMCSourceCode cls1source;
        final InMemoryCompiler.IMCSourceCode cls2source;

        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("package toast;\n");
        sb.append("public class DynaClass {\n");
        sb.append("    public static void main(final String[] args) {");
        sb.append("        System.out.println(\"Based massively on the work of Rekha Kumari, http://javapracs.blogspot.de/2011/06/dynamic-in-memory-compilation-using.html\");\n");
        sb.append("        System.out.println(\"This is the main method speaking.\");\n");
        sb.append("        System.out.println(\"Args: \" + java.util.Arrays.toString(args));\n");
        sb.append("        final Test test = new Test();\n");
        sb.append("    }\n");
        sb.append("    public String toString() {\n");
        sb.append("        return \"Hello, I am \" + ");
        sb.append("this.getClass().getSimpleName();\n");
        sb.append("    }\n");
        sb.append("}\n");
        cls1source = new InMemoryCompiler.IMCSourceCode("toast.DynaClass", sb.toString());

        sb.setLength(0);
        sb.append("package toast;\n");
        sb.append("public class Test {\n");
        sb.append("    public Test() {\n");
        sb.append("        System.out.println(\"class Test constructor reporting in.\");\n");
        sb.append("        System.out.println(new DynaClass());\n");
        sb.append("    }\n");
        sb.append("}\n");
        cls2source = new InMemoryCompiler.IMCSourceCode("toast.Test", sb.toString());

        final List<InMemoryCompiler.IMCSourceCode> classSources = new ArrayList<>();
        classSources.add(cls1source);
        classSources.add(cls2source);

        final InMemoryCompiler uCompiler = new InMemoryCompiler(classSources);
        final CompilerFeedback compilerFeedback = uCompiler.compile();
        System.out.println("\n\nCOMPILER FEEDBACK: " + compilerFeedback);

        if (compilerFeedback != null && compilerFeedback.success) {

            try {
                System.out.println("\nTOSTRING DEMO:");
                uCompiler.runToString(cls1source.fullClassName);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                System.out.println("\nMAIN DEMO:");
                uCompiler.runMain(cls1source.fullClassName, new String[] { "test1", "test2" });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

COMPILER CLASS:

```
import javax.tools.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URI;
import java.security.SecureClassLoader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * MASSIVELY based on http://javapracs.blogspot.de/2011/06/dynamic-in-memory-compilation-using.html by Rekha Kumari
 * (June 2011)
 */
final public class InMemoryCompiler {

    final public static class IMCSourceCode {

        final public String fullClassName;
        final public String sourceCode;

        /**
         * @param fullClassName Full name of the class that will be compiled. If the class should be in some package,
         *                      fullName should contain it too, for example: "testpackage.DynaClass"
         * @param sourceCode    the source code
         */
        public IMCSourceCode(final String fullClassName, final String sourceCode) {

            this.fullClassName = fullClassName;
            this.sourceCode = sourceCode;
        }
    }

    final public boolean valid;

    final private List<IMCSourceCode> classSourceCodes;
    final private JavaFileManager fileManager;

    public InMemoryCompiler(final List<IMCSourceCode> classSourceCodes) {

        this.classSourceCodes = classSourceCodes;

        final JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        if (compiler == null) {
            fileManager = null;
            valid = false;
            System.err.println("ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() returned null! This program needs to be run on a system with an installed JDK.");
            return;
        }
        valid = true;

        fileManager = new ForwardingJavaFileManager<JavaFileManager>(compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null)) {

            final private Map<String, ByteArrayOutputStream> byteStreams = new HashMap<>();

            @Override
            public ClassLoader getClassLoader(final Location location) {

                return new SecureClassLoader() {

                    @Override
                    protected Class<?> findClass(final String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {

                        final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = byteStreams.get(className);
                        if (bos == null) {
                            return null;
                        }
                        final byte[] b = bos.toByteArray();
                        return super.defineClass(className, b, 0, b.length);
                    }
                };
            }

            @Override
            public JavaFileObject getJavaFileForOutput(final Location location, final String className, final JavaFileObject.Kind kind, final FileObject sibling) throws IOException {

                return new SimpleJavaFileObject(URI.create("string:///" + className.replace('.', '/') + kind.extension), kind) {

                    @Override
                    public OutputStream openOutputStream() throws IOException {

                        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = byteStreams.get(className);
                        if (bos == null) {
                            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            byteStreams.put(className, bos);
                        }
                        return bos;
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }

    public CompilerFeedback compile() {

        if (!valid) {
            return null;
        }
        final List<JavaFileObject> files = new ArrayList<>();
        for (IMCSourceCode classSourceCode : classSourceCodes) {
            URI uri = null;
            try {
                uri = URI.create("string:///" + classSourceCode.fullClassName.replace('.', '/') + JavaFileObject.Kind.SOURCE.extension);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (uri != null) {
                final SimpleJavaFileObject sjfo = new SimpleJavaFileObject(uri, JavaFileObject.Kind.SOURCE) {

                    @Override
                    public CharSequence getCharContent(final boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {

                        return classSourceCode.sourceCode;
                    }
                };
                files.add(sjfo);
            }
        }

        final DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<>();

        final JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

        if (files.size() > 0) {
            final JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null, null, files);
            return new CompilerFeedback(task.call(), diagnostics);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void runToString(final String className) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {

        if (!valid) {
            return;
        }
        final Class<?> theClass = getCompiledClass(className);
        final Object instance = theClass.newInstance();
        System.out.println(instance);
    }

    public void runMain(final String className, final String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {

        if (!valid) {
            return;
        }
        final Class<?> theClass = getCompiledClass(className);
        final Method mainMethod = theClass.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
        mainMethod.invoke(null, new Object[] { args });
    }

    public Class<?> getCompiledClass(final String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        if (!valid) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("InMemoryCompiler instance not usable because ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() returned null: No JDK installed.");
        }
        final ClassLoader classLoader = fileManager.getClassLoader(null);
        final Class<?> ret = classLoader.loadClass(className);
        if (ret == null) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException("Class returned by ClassLoader was null!");
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

COMPILERFEEDBACK CLASS:

```
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;
import javax.tools.DiagnosticCollector;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.SimpleJavaFileObject;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

final public class CompilerFeedback {

    final public boolean success;
    final public List<CompilerMessage> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    public CompilerFeedback(final Boolean success, final DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics) {

        this.success = success != null && success;
        for (Diagnostic<? extends JavaFileObject> diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) {
            messages.add(new CompilerMessage(diagnostic));
        }
    }

    public String toString() {

        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("SUCCESS: ").append(success).append('\n');
        final int iTop = messages.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < iTop; i++) {
            sb.append("\n[MESSAGE ").append(i + 1).append(" OF ").append(iTop).append("]\n\n");
            // sb.append(messages.get(i).toString()).append("\n");
            // sb.append(messages.get(i).toStringForList()).append("\n");
            sb.append(messages.get(i).toStringForDebugging()).append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    final public static class CompilerMessage {

        final public Diagnostic<? extends JavaFileObject> compilerInfo;

        final public String typeOfProblem;
        final public String typeOfProblem_forDebugging;

        final public String multiLineMessage;

        final public int lineNumber;
        final public int columnNumber;

        final public int textHighlightPos_lineStart;
        final public int textHighlightPos_problemStart;
        final public int textHighlightPos_problemEnd;

        final public String sourceCode;
        final public String codeOfConcern;
        final public String codeOfConcernLong;

        CompilerMessage(final Diagnostic<? extends JavaFileObject> diagnostic) {

            final JavaFileObject sourceFileObject = diagnostic.getSource();
            String sourceCodePreliminary = null;
            if (sourceFileObject instanceof SimpleJavaFileObject) {
                final SimpleJavaFileObject simpleSourceFileObject = (SimpleJavaFileObject) sourceFileObject;

                try {
                    final CharSequence charSequence = simpleSourceFileObject.getCharContent(false);
                    sourceCodePreliminary = charSequence.toString();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (sourceCodePreliminary == null) {
                sourceCode = "[SOURCE CODE UNAVAILABLE]";
            } else {
                sourceCode = sourceCodePreliminary;
            }

            compilerInfo = diagnostic;

            typeOfProblem = diagnostic.getKind().name();
            typeOfProblem_forDebugging = "toString() = " + diagnostic.getKind().toString() + "; name() = " + typeOfProblem;

            lineNumber = (int) compilerInfo.getLineNumber();
            columnNumber = (int) compilerInfo.getColumnNumber();

            final int sourceLen = sourceCode.length();
            textHighlightPos_lineStart = (int) Math.min(Math.max(0, diagnostic.getStartPosition()), sourceLen);
            textHighlightPos_problemStart = (int) Math.min(Math.max(0, diagnostic.getPosition()), sourceLen);
            textHighlightPos_problemEnd = (int) Math.min(Math.max(0, diagnostic.getEndPosition()), sourceLen);

            final StringBuilder reformattedMessage = new StringBuilder();
            final String message = diagnostic.getMessage(Locale.US);
            final int messageCutOffPosition = message.indexOf("location:");
            final String[] messageParts;
            if (messageCutOffPosition >= 0) {
                messageParts = message.substring(0, messageCutOffPosition).split("\n");
            } else {
                messageParts = message.split("\n");
            }
            for (String s : messageParts) {
                String s2 = s.trim();
                if (s2.length() > 0) {
                    boolean lengthChanged;
                    do {
                        final int lBeforeReplace = s2.length();
                        s2 = s2.replace("  ", " ");
                        lengthChanged = (s2.length() != lBeforeReplace);
                    } while (lengthChanged);
                    reformattedMessage.append(s2).append("\n");
                }
            }

            codeOfConcern = sourceCode.substring(textHighlightPos_problemStart, textHighlightPos_problemEnd);
            codeOfConcernLong = sourceCode.substring(textHighlightPos_lineStart, textHighlightPos_problemEnd);
            if (!codeOfConcern.isEmpty()) {
                reformattedMessage.append("Code of concern: \"").append(codeOfConcern).append('\"');
            }
            multiLineMessage = reformattedMessage.toString();
        }

        public String toStringForList() {

            if (compilerInfo == null) {
                return "No compiler!";
            } else {
                return compilerInfo.getCode();
            }
        }

        public String toStringForDebugging() {

            final StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();

            ret.append("Type of problem: ").append(typeOfProblem_forDebugging).append("\n\n");
            ret.append("Message:\n").append(multiLineMessage).append("\n\n");

            ret.append(compilerInfo.getCode()).append("\n\n");

            ret.append("line number: ").append(lineNumber).append("\n");
            ret.append("column number: ").append(columnNumber).append("\n");

            ret.append("textHighlightPos_lineStart: ").append(textHighlightPos_lineStart).append("\n");
            ret.append("textHighlightPos_problemStart: ").append(textHighlightPos_problemStart).append("\n");
            ret.append("textHighlightPos_problemEnd: ").append(textHighlightPos_problemEnd).append("\n");

            return ret.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {

            //            return compilerInfo.getMessage(Locale.US);
            return typeOfProblem + ": " + multiLineMessage + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

UTILITY METHOD (Not needed for the three classes further up.):

```
final public static String PREFIX_CLASSNAME = "class ";
final public static String PREFIX_PACKAGENAME = "package ";
final public static String CHARSET_JAVAKEYWORDENDERS = " \n[](){}<>;,\"\\/*+-=%!&?@:";

/**
 * @return e.g. "com.dreamspacepresident.TestClass" if the source's first root level "class" (I'm talking about {}
 * hierarchy.) is named "TestClass", and if the "package" name is "com.dreamspacepresident". Null is returned if
 * sourceCode is null or does not provide a class name. (Mind that the parsing is done in a quite crappy way.)
 */
public static String deriveFullClassNameFromSource(final String sourceCode) {

    if (sourceCode == null) {
        return null;
    }
    final int firstBr = sourceCode.indexOf('{');
    if (firstBr >= 0) {
        // DETERMINE CLASS NAME
        final int firstClass = sourceCode.indexOf(PREFIX_CLASSNAME);
        if (firstClass < firstBr) {
            String className = sourceCode.substring(firstClass + PREFIX_CLASSNAME.length(), firstBr).trim();
            final int classNameEnd = indexOfAnyOfThese(className, CHARSET_JAVAKEYWORDENDERS);
            if (classNameEnd >= 0) {
                className = className.substring(0, classNameEnd);
            }
            if (!className.isEmpty()) {
                // DETERMINE PACKAGE NAME
                String packageName = null;
                final int firstPackage = sourceCode.indexOf(PREFIX_PACKAGENAME);
                if (firstPackage >= 0 && firstPackage < firstBr && firstPackage < firstClass) {
                    packageName = sourceCode.substring(firstPackage + PREFIX_PACKAGENAME.length(), firstBr).trim();
                    final int packageNameEnd = indexOfAnyOfThese(packageName, CHARSET_JAVAKEYWORDENDERS);
                    if (packageNameEnd >= 0) {
                        packageName = packageName.substring(0, packageNameEnd);
                    }
                }
                return (packageName != null && !packageName.isEmpty() ? packageName + "." : "") + className;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}


/**
 * Looks for the first occurrence of ANY of the given characters, which is easier than using a bunch of
 * String.indexOf() calls.
 *
 * @return -1 if not found, otherwise the String index of the first hit
 */
public static int indexOfAnyOfThese(final String text, final String characters) {

    if (text != null && !text.isEmpty() && characters != null && !characters.isEmpty()) {
        final int lenT = text.length();
        final int lenC = characters.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < lenT; i++) {
            final char c = text.charAt(i);
            for (int ii = 0; ii < lenC; ii++) {
                if (c == characters.charAt(ii)) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but this is not returning updated compiled (already exist) class it compile only (existing)java code not string (updated source code)

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a library to do this a few years ago. It takes a String which can contain nested classes, compiles them and optionally loads them into the current class loader (so you don't need an additional class loader) If the JVM is running in debug mode it will write the generated code to a file so you can step through your generated code.

http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2010_11_01_archive.html

---

To paraphrase the example from `erolagnab` you can do

```
StringBuilder sourceCode = new StringBuilder();
sourceCode.append("package org.mdkt;\n")
          .append("public class HelloClass {\n")
          .append("   public String hello() { return \"hello\"; }")
          .append("}");

Class<?> helloClass = CACHED_COMPILER.compile("org.mdkt.HelloClass",
                                              sourceCode.toString());
```

Update, the source is available here https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Runtime-Compiler

And you can obtain the latest build via maven http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C842970587

---

A longer example.

```
// this writes the file to disk only when debugging is enabled.
CachedCompiler cc = CompilerUtils.DEBUGGING ?
        new CachedCompiler(new File(parent, "src/test/java"), new File(parent, "target/compiled")) :
        CompilerUtils.CACHED_COMPILER;

String text = "generated test " + new Date();
Class fooBarTeeClass = cc.loadFromJava("eg.FooBarTee", "package eg;\n" +
    '\n' +
    "import eg.components.BarImpl;\n" +
    "import eg.components.TeeImpl;\n" +
    "import eg.components.Foo;\n" +
    '\n' +
    "public class FooBarTee{\n" +
    "    public final String name;\n" +
    "    public final TeeImpl tee;\n" +
    "    public final BarImpl bar;\n" +
    "    public final BarImpl copy;\n" +
    "    public final Foo foo;\n" +
    '\n' +
    "    public FooBarTee(String name) {\n" +
    "        // when viewing this file, ensure it is synchronised with the copy on disk.\n" +
    "        System.out.println(\"" + text + "\");\n" +
    "        this.name = name;\n" +
    '\n' +
    "        tee = new TeeImpl(\"test\");\n" +
    '\n' +
    "        bar = new BarImpl(tee, 55);\n" +
    '\n' +
    "        copy = new BarImpl(tee, 555);\n" +
    '\n' +
    "        // you should see the current date here after synchronisation.\n" +
    "        foo = new Foo(bar, copy, \"" + text + "\", 5);\n" +
    "    }\n" +
    '\n' +
    "    public void start() {\n" +
    "    }\n" +
    '\n' +
    "    public void stop() {\n" +
    "    }\n" +
    '\n' +
    "    public void close() {\n" +
    "        stop();\n" +
    '\n' +
    "    }\n" +
    "}\n");

// add a debug break point here and step into this method.
FooBarTee fooBarTee = new FooBarTee("test foo bar tee");
Foo foo = fooBarTee.foo;
assertNotNull(foo);
assertEquals(text, foo.s);
```

Comment: @DavidKroukamp It worth noting that this can be used to modify a class before it is loaded which is why the code example compiles. i.e. it is compiled using a stub class which is changed at runtime allowing you to compile and run it without reflection. ;)

Comment: I might have missed it... but I don't see a license.  Is this free to use commercially if we reference your name/contribution? :)

Comment: @JohnHumphreys-w00te It is Apache 2.0, so free for use.

Comment: @JohnHumphreys-w00te Btw the library has been open source since 2010 and I know a few banks which are using it indirectly.

Comment: @JohnHumphreys-w00te the version on maven central should have an Apache 2.0 license.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted:

- **in-memory compilation of a java file** (useful for Java as a scripting language)
- No additional dependencies (easy to setup)
- Implementation in as low number of files as possible (easy to incorporate in a project)

You can try it first here: http://ideone.com/cu1GhE#view_edit_box

The following code is based on [Rekha Kumari](http://javapracs.blogspot.de/2011/06/dynamic-in-memory-compilation-using.html) code:

**Main.java**

```
package com.mycompany.java;

//import org.slf4j.Logger;
//import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    //private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        try {
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer);
            out.println("package com.mycompany.script;");
            out.println("");
            out.println("public class HelloWorld {");
            out.println("  public static void main(String args[]) {");
            out.println("    System.out.println(\"This is in another java file\");");
            out.println("  }");
            out.println("}");
            out.close();

            String fullName = "com.mycompany.script.HelloWorld";
            String src = writer.toString();

            DynamicCompiler uCompiler = new DynamicCompiler(fullName, src);
            uCompiler.compile();
            uCompiler.run();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //logger.error("Exception:", e);
            System.out.print("Exception");
        }
    }    
}
```

**DynamicCompiler.java**

```
package com.mycompany.java;

//import org.slf4j.Logger;
//import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.tools.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.security.SecureClassLoader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

// Based on: http://javapracs.blogspot.cz/2011/06/dynamic-in-memory-compilation-using.html
public class DynamicCompiler {
    //private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DynamicCompiler.class);

    private JavaFileManager fileManager;
    private String fullName;
    private String sourceCode;

    public DynamicCompiler(String fullName, String srcCode) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.sourceCode = srcCode;
        this.fileManager = initFileManager();
    }

    public JavaFileManager initFileManager() {
        if (fileManager != null)
            return fileManager;
        else {
            JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
            fileManager = new
                    ClassFileManager(compiler
                    .getStandardFileManager(null, null, null));
            return fileManager;
        }
    }

    public void compile() {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();    
        List<JavaFileObject> files = new ArrayList<>();
        files.add(new CharSequenceJavaFileObject(fullName, sourceCode));

        compiler.getTask(
                null,
                fileManager,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                files
        ).call();
    }

    public void run() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            fileManager
                    .getClassLoader(null)
                    .loadClass(fullName)
                    .getDeclaredMethod("main", new Class[]{String[].class})
                    .invoke(null, new Object[]{null});
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            System.out.print("InvocationTargetException");
            //logger.error("InvocationTargetException:", e);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            System.out.print("NoSuchMethodException ");
            //logger.error("NoSuchMethodException:", e);
        }
    }

    public class CharSequenceJavaFileObject extends SimpleJavaFileObject {

        /**
         * CharSequence representing the source code to be compiled
         */
        private CharSequence content;

        public CharSequenceJavaFileObject(String className, CharSequence content) {
            super(URI.create("string:///" + className.replace('.', '/') + Kind.SOURCE.extension), Kind.SOURCE);
            this.content = content;
        }

        public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
            return content;
        }
    }

    public class ClassFileManager extends ForwardingJavaFileManager {
        private JavaClassObject javaClassObject;

        public ClassFileManager(StandardJavaFileManager standardManager) {
            super(standardManager);
        }

        @Override
        public ClassLoader getClassLoader(Location location) {
            return new SecureClassLoader() {
                @Override
                protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
                    byte[] b = javaClassObject.getBytes();
                    return super.defineClass(name, javaClassObject.getBytes(), 0, b.length);
                }
            };
        }

        public JavaFileObject getJavaFileForOutput(Location location, String className, JavaFileObject.Kind kind, FileObject sibling) throws IOException {
            this.javaClassObject = new JavaClassObject(className, kind);
            return this.javaClassObject;
        }
    }

    public class JavaClassObject extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
        protected final ByteArrayOutputStream bos =
                new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        public JavaClassObject(String name, Kind kind) {
            super(URI.create("string:///" + name.replace('.', '/')
                    + kind.extension), kind);
        }

        public byte[] getBytes() {
            return bos.toByteArray();
        }

        @Override
        public OutputStream openOutputStream() throws IOException {
            return bos;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using this example and but i want to be able to store an instance and it's state in my run.

For example in the compile method i want to call 
`Object instance = fileManager.getClassLoader(null).loadClass(name).newInstance();`
and in the run i want to use that `instance` variable as the first param for the invoke method call but that doesnt work because invoke expects an instance of the declaring class, not object.

Is there anyway i can make this work?

Comment: Well, I believe you can do it. You just have to modify the sample code to add a second class to the `DynamicCompiler` class. Then you create your object instance and pass it `.invoke(null, new Object[]{null});` call as one of parameters. Without details, it's hard to help further. Maybe you should post it as a new question. :-)

Comment: Okay, thank you for getting back to me. If i cannot resolve this myself ill post another question about it and link it here.

Comment: I have achieved the desired functionality. For anyone else looking to create an instance of their class and use it repeatedly, this is what I did. 
* I made an interface explaining the in-memory class, and made the class implement that interface.
* In compile I wrote  `[interface] instance = fileManager.getClassLoader(null).loadClass(name).asSubclass([interface].class).newInstance‌​();`
* In run I wrote `instance.[methodName]()`

Comment: Why am i not getting updated source code class file still getting old class using jdk 14 assist me

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to introduce my solution which runs well in production.

Here are the three source code files.

MemoryJavaCompiler.java

```
package me.soulmachine.compiler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.tools.*;

/**
 * Simple interface to Java compiler using JSR 199 Compiler API.
 */
public class MemoryJavaCompiler {
    private javax.tools.JavaCompiler tool;
    private StandardJavaFileManager stdManager;

    public MemoryJavaCompiler() {
        tool = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        if (tool == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get Java compiler. Please, ensure that JDK is used instead of JRE.");
        }
        stdManager = tool.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Compile a single static method.
     */
    public Method compileStaticMethod(final String methodName, final String className,
        final String source)
        throws ClassNotFoundException {
        final Map<String, byte[]> classBytes = compile(className + ".java", source);
        final MemoryClassLoader classLoader = new MemoryClassLoader(classBytes);
        final Class clazz = classLoader.loadClass(className);
        final Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (final Method method : methods) {
            if (method.getName().equals(methodName)) {
                if (!method.isAccessible()) method.setAccessible(true);
                return method;
            }
        }
        throw new NoSuchMethodError(methodName);
    }


    public Map<String, byte[]> compile(String fileName, String source) {
        return compile(fileName, source, new PrintWriter(System.err), null, null);
    }


    /**
     * compile given String source and return bytecodes as a Map.
     *
     * @param fileName source fileName to be used for error messages etc.
     * @param source Java source as String
     * @param err error writer where diagnostic messages are written
     * @param sourcePath location of additional .java source files
     * @param classPath location of additional .class files
     */
    private Map<String, byte[]> compile(String fileName, String source,
        Writer err, String sourcePath, String classPath) {
        // to collect errors, warnings etc.
        DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics =
            new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();

        // create a new memory JavaFileManager
        MemoryJavaFileManager fileManager = new MemoryJavaFileManager(stdManager);

        // prepare the compilation unit
        List<JavaFileObject> compUnits = new ArrayList<JavaFileObject>(1);
        compUnits.add(fileManager.makeStringSource(fileName, source));

        return compile(compUnits, fileManager, err, sourcePath, classPath);
    }

    private Map<String, byte[]> compile(final List<JavaFileObject> compUnits, 
        final MemoryJavaFileManager fileManager,
        Writer err, String sourcePath, String classPath) {
        // to collect errors, warnings etc.
        DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics =
            new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();

        // javac options
        List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
        options.add("-Xlint:all");
        //      options.add("-g:none");
        options.add("-deprecation");
        if (sourcePath != null) {
            options.add("-sourcepath");
            options.add(sourcePath);
        }

        if (classPath != null) {
            options.add("-classpath");
            options.add(classPath);
        }

        // create a compilation task
        javax.tools.JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task =
            tool.getTask(err, fileManager, diagnostics,
                options, null, compUnits);

        if (task.call() == false) {
            PrintWriter perr = new PrintWriter(err);
            for (Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) {
                perr.println(diagnostic);
            }
            perr.flush();
            return null;
        }

        Map<String, byte[]> classBytes = fileManager.getClassBytes();
        try {
            fileManager.close();
        } catch (IOException exp) {
        }

        return classBytes;
    }
}
```

MemoryJavaFileManager.java

```
package me.soulmachine.compiler;


import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilterOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.tools.FileObject;
import javax.tools.ForwardingJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.JavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject.Kind;
import javax.tools.SimpleJavaFileObject;

/**
 * JavaFileManager that keeps compiled .class bytes in memory.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
final class MemoryJavaFileManager extends ForwardingJavaFileManager {

    /** Java source file extension. */
    private final static String EXT = ".java";

    private Map<String, byte[]> classBytes;

    public MemoryJavaFileManager(JavaFileManager fileManager) {
        super(fileManager);
        classBytes = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Map<String, byte[]> getClassBytes() {
        return classBytes;
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        classBytes = null;
    }

    public void flush() throws IOException {
    }

    /**
     * A file object used to represent Java source coming from a string.
     */
    private static class StringInputBuffer extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
        final String code;

        StringInputBuffer(String fileName, String code) {
            super(toURI(fileName), Kind.SOURCE);
            this.code = code;
        }

        public CharBuffer getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
            return CharBuffer.wrap(code);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A file object that stores Java bytecode into the classBytes map.
     */
    private class ClassOutputBuffer extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
        private String name;

        ClassOutputBuffer(String name) {
            super(toURI(name), Kind.CLASS);
            this.name = name;
        }

        public OutputStream openOutputStream() {
            return new FilterOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                public void close() throws IOException {
                    out.close();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = (ByteArrayOutputStream)out;
                    classBytes.put(name, bos.toByteArray());
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public JavaFileObject getJavaFileForOutput(JavaFileManager.Location location,
        String className,
        Kind kind,
        FileObject sibling) throws IOException {
        if (kind == Kind.CLASS) {
            return new ClassOutputBuffer(className);
        } else {
            return super.getJavaFileForOutput(location, className, kind, sibling);
        }
    }

    static JavaFileObject makeStringSource(String fileName, String code) {
        return new StringInputBuffer(fileName, code);
    }

    static URI toURI(String name) {
        File file = new File(name);
        if (file.exists()) {
            return file.toURI();
        } else {
            try {
                final StringBuilder newUri = new StringBuilder();
                newUri.append("mfm:///");
                newUri.append(name.replace('.', '/'));
                if(name.endsWith(EXT)) newUri.replace(newUri.length() - EXT.length(), newUri.length(), EXT);
                return URI.create(newUri.toString());
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                return URI.create("mfm:///com/sun/script/java/java_source");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MemoryClassLoader.java

```
package me.soulmachine.compiler;


import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

/**
 * ClassLoader that loads .class bytes from memory.
 */
final class MemoryClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {
    private Map<String, byte[]> classBytes;

    public MemoryClassLoader(Map<String, byte[]> classBytes,
        String classPath, ClassLoader parent) {
        super(toURLs(classPath), parent);
        this.classBytes = classBytes;
    }

    public MemoryClassLoader(Map<String, byte[]> classBytes, String classPath) {
        this(classBytes, classPath, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
    }

    public MemoryClassLoader(Map<String, byte[]> classBytes) {
        this(classBytes, null, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
    }

    public Class load(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return loadClass(className);
    }

    public Iterable<Class> loadAll() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>(classBytes.size());
        for (String name : classBytes.keySet()) {
            classes.add(loadClass(name));
        }
        return classes;
    }

    protected Class findClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        byte[] buf = classBytes.get(className);
        if (buf != null) {
            // clear the bytes in map -- we don't need it anymore
            classBytes.put(className, null);
            return defineClass(className, buf, 0, buf.length);
        } else {
            return super.findClass(className);
        }
    }

    private static URL[] toURLs(String classPath) {
        if (classPath == null) {
            return new URL[0];
        }

        List<URL> list = new ArrayList<URL>();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(classPath, File.pathSeparator);
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String token = st.nextToken();
            File file = new File(token);
            if (file.exists()) {
                try {
                    list.add(file.toURI().toURL());
                } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {}
            } else {
                try {
                    list.add(new URL(token));
                } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {}
            }
        }
        URL[] res = new URL[list.size()];
        list.toArray(res);
        return res;
    }
}
```

**Explanations**:

1. In order to represent a  Java source file in memory instead of disk, I defined a `StringInputBuffer` class in the `MemoryJavaFileManager.java`.
2. To save the compiled `.class` files in memory, I implemented a class `MemoryJavaFileManager`.  The main idea is to override the function `getJavaFileForOutput()` to store bytecodes into a map.
3. To load the bytecodes in memory, I have to implement a customized classloader `MemoryClassLoader`, which reads bytecodes in the map and turn them into classes.

Here is a unite test.

```
package me.soulmachine.compiler;


import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class MemoryJavaCompilerTest {
    private final static MemoryJavaCompiler compiler = new MemoryJavaCompiler();

    @Test public void compileStaticMethodTest()
        throws ClassNotFoundException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        final String source = "public final class Solution {\n"
            + "public static String greeting(String name) {\n"
            + "\treturn \"Hello \" + name;\n" + "}\n}\n";
        final Method greeting = compiler.compileStaticMethod("greeting", "Solution", source);
        final Object result = greeting.invoke(null, "soulmachine");
        assertEquals("Hello soulmachine", result.toString());
    }
}
```

### Reference

1. [JavaCompiler.java from Cloudera Morphlines](https://github.com/kite-sdk/kite/tree/master/kite-morphlines/kite-morphlines-core/src/main/java/org/kitesdk/morphline/scriptengine/java)
2. [How to create an object from a string in Java (how to eval a string)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168931/how-to-create-an-object-from-a-string-in-java-how-to-eval-a-string)
3. [InMemoryJavaCompiler](https://github.com/trung/InMemoryJavaCompiler)
4. [Java-Runtime-Compiler](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Runtime-Compiler)
5. [动态的Java - 无废话JavaCompilerAPI中文指南]
6. [Compile and Run Java Source Code in Memory](http://www.soulmachine.me/blog/2015/07/22/compile-and-run-java-source-code-in-memory/).

Answer (score -2):

```
String fileToCompile = ;
JavaCompile compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
if(
    compiler.run(null, null, null, "PACKAGE_NAME" + java.io.File.separator +"CLASS_NAME.java") == 0
)
    System.out.println("Compilation is successful");
else
    System.out.println("Compilation Failed");
```