# Compile and emit bytecode from generated code

Tags: java, bytecode

Is it possible to compile and emit .class files at run time? I have some generated servlet code and I want to compile them into classes and package it as a war.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you Google for `javax.tool.JavaCompiler`? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html

Comment: Yes, but how do I write the generated classes to disk?

Comment: A way forward seems to be an override of `javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager`, but I've never attempted that. Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173294/compiling-fully-in-memory-with-javax-tools-javacompiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just export the generated codes into files in a temp directory, invoke javac in there, package them, serve them. Nothing fancy needed.

Comment: This worked out just fine for me. Thanks for idea. I have uploaded the basic prototype on github (https://github.com/adeydas/Compilation-Unit) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

You can take a look at the [Java Compiler API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)

Note however, that you will have to provide the corresponding ClassLoader and manage all the resources yourself.

If you want to generate bytecode from non-Java sources, you can also use [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/index.html) directly: