# cmd open and close immediately while opening java

Tags: java, cmd

I am creating a code editor for Java source files by using Java. When I click on the `RUN` menu, it perfectly opens `cmd` and run `javac` command, but the problem is that it immediately gets closed and I want something like pause.

This is my code:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
    rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start java Maq");
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

How to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Javac? But in your code you have java command? Explain what do you mean by pause

Comment: @shazin javac and java same same :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15464449/4108070) question helped me :)

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                try {
                    rt.exec("cmd.exe /c cd /d d: & start cmd.exe /k javac Maq.java");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Now that you have confirmed that you actually need javac and are working on an IDE/editor, the right way to handle compiling errors is by compiling from the JRE using `javax.tools.JavaCompiler`.

The `JavaCompiler` gives you refined control, cross platform functionality and is always there. You can take a look at [the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) to get yourself started. Here's [a nice example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12173346/4109287) of its usage.

I have used it personally for an IDE like project and it did exactly what you would expect from an in-program compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The 'start' bit of your command detaches Java from the cmd process.

You're probably best off writing a batch script containing something like this:

```
@echo off
java Maq
pause
```

Then just call that batch file using Runtime.exec(...)

Comment: but my code editor may have multiple tabs so shld i every time creates a batch file for evry tab to run them out??

Comment: Java is OS-independent by default, and this is very bad practice as well (no arguments ...)

Comment: maq, you could use arguments in the batch script. But msrd0 is right, and I completely agree with him, albeit no Runtime.exec call is cross platform when things like cmd.exe are involved. The proper solution is to use Java's Process functionality or as I posted as a new answer, the built in compiler

Answer (score 0):

To see `javac`'s output, you can't use `Runtime.exec()`. Use a [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead. Your code can look something like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("javac", "Maq.java");
pb.directory(new File("/path/to/source/code/"));

Process p = pb.start();
InputStream in = p.getInputStream(); // this is connected to the System.out from javac
int exit = p.waitFor(); // wait for javac to finish

StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
char[] buf = new char[1024]; int read;
while ((read = in.read(buf)) != -1)
    text.append(new String(buf, 0, read));
text.append("\n\njavac returned with exit code ").append(exit);

// display text - it now contains javac's output and its exit code
JFrame f = new JFrame("javac's output");
JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
tp.setText(text.toString());
tp.setEditable(false);
f.setContentPane(tp);
f.setSize(500, 400); // or whatever
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: @maq why don't you create a `JFrame` with a `JTextPane` (or similar) and show the text in it?

Comment: @maq Please see my edit, and javac never asks for input

Comment: i got you but i m sorry i did not mention i also want `java` command to run

Comment: @maq How about adding a `JTextField` below the `JTextPane` to make that possible?

Comment: @maq It's not that complicated (I can provide the code if you want), but if you're looking after an OS-dependent solution, write a batch script like _Mitchell_ suggested

Comment: kindly provide plzz :)

Comment: thn ur great thnk u so much waiting

Comment: There is no such method called "pb.setDirectory" in ProcessBuilder class

Comment: @MertSerimer It looks like the `setDirectory` method was renamed to `directory` (see the javadoc link in the answer). Thanks for pointing this out, I'll edit my answer