# In-memory compilation with more than one class per file

Tags: java, in-memory, java-compiler-api

**First of all what i try to achieve:**
I want to compile java classes dynamically in-memory, during runtime. Basically with the provided Java Compiler API thats not really big of a deal, but when it comes to multiple classes per .java file I'm lost.

**What i got so far:**
I'm currently working with the `InMemoryJavaCompiler` provided in an answer to this question ([Compile code fully in memory with javax.tools.JavaCompiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173294/compiling-fully-in-memory-with-javax-tools-javacompiler))

As described above, the compilation of single classes per file is no problem, but I want to be able to compile pretty much any valid .java files.

For example the file (`FileOne.java`) I try to compile looks like this:

```
package test;
public class FileOne {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
class Functions {
    public static int test(int x) {
        return -x;
    }
}
```

When i try to compile this file like `InMemoryJavaCompiler.compile("test.FileOne", source)`, I get an Exception marking the `defineClass(...)` line in the overwritten ClassLoader that says:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Extra bytes at the end of class file test/FileOne
```

This problem also exists with inner classes, but there it is only some kind of naming/calling problem, I guess:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test/FileOne (wrong name: test/FileOne$Functions)
```

Comment: Are you sure you can have more than 1 class per file? I didn't dive in into `InMemoryJavaCompiler` but by default there should be the only Class per file.

Comment: As i know java only limits the public class per file to 1. The `InMemoryJavaCompiler` was just to show you my current position, as I try to solve this problem step-by-step. If there are other ways to my wished solution, I'm willing to switch it out

Comment: have u considered using ant?

Comment: @nafas Maybe I missed something, but I'm not sure how Ant provides runtime compilation features, which could help in my case. It would be nice if you could explain your thought a bit more in detail

Comment: @ceekay as I understood you case you want to compile a project (with multiple classes in different folders and etc) you could write a generalized ant builder (build.xml)  to compile your project e.g. if your project style is like eclipse (src,lib and etc). then you can simply call ProcessBuilder for ant

Comment: @nafas Ok sry when it wasn't clear. I want to compile java classes dynamically in-memory, during runtime. Therefore i guess a general build.xml would do the job

Comment: @ceekay lemme know if you need an example ant builder

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right that `InMemoryJavaCompilation` as-is currently available on github does not work if a class has inner or anonymous classes. I have experienced exactly the same problem that you described.

After a long searching I found [JSCC](https://github.com/verhas/jscc) which is very complete. Thanks to verhas (github user name) for developing it and making it available. I tested JSCC with nested classes and it works fine. You can find the code and how to use it on Github.

https://github.com/verhas/jscc

As far as I understood, the problem with `InMemoryJavaCompilation` is that it stores one `byte array` per class. However, compiler generates more than one classes for a class with nested classes or anonymous classes. In that case, `InMemoryJavaCompilation` stores only the last class returned by the compiler, and that may not be the top level class. Therefore, you may get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. JSCC maintains a `Byte Array Map` to keep the compiled code of all the classes.

Although you asked this question long time back, I hope this helps.