# Using string input as boolean

Tags: java, boolean, user-input

```
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(Boolean.parseBoolean(input));
```

So my inputs look like `1 > 2` or `false || true`, but I'm not getting the correct values.

But when I call:

```
    Boolean x = 1 < 2;
    System.out.println(x);
```

I get them correct. So my question is. *How do I convert String input to return boolean value?*

So far tried:

```
    Boolean.parseBoolean();
    Boolean.getBoolean();
    Boolean.valueOf();
```

Thanks for your answers.

**EDIT**

```
INPUT         -  OUTPUT
1 < 2         -  false(should be true)
false || true -  false(should be true)
```

Comment: What values are you getting when executing the code? please share it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ScriptEngine` for this:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String input = "1 > 2";
System.out.println(engine.eval(input)); //prints false
```

Comment: I actually had this done in js, but I had no idea there was such thing as ScriptEngine, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

`Boolean.parseBoolean(String)` is implemented as:

```
public static boolean parseBoolean(String s) {
    return ((s != null) && s.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
}
```

So it returns `true` if the input string is not null and equals `true` (ignoring case). Else `false` is returned.

You seem to expect that `Boolean.parseBoolean(String)` accepts an expression string and *evaluates* the string, but that is simply not the case.

Answer (score 1):

While you write `System.out.println(1<2);` it works because there is a overloaded version of `println()` which takes boolean value. But when you pass a string, it will be considered as String only, NOT `boolean`.

In addition, `Boolean.parseBoolean()` always takes boolean value(true\false) in string format as parameter and returns corresponding value in boolean format, otherwise it will always return false

Answer (score 0):

Boolean.parseBoolean does the following, according to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean%28java.lang.String%29):

> public static boolean parseBoolean(String s)
>
> Parses the string argument as a boolean. The boolean returned
>   represents the value true if the string argument is not null and is
>   equal, ignoring case, to the string "true".

You're attempting to pass in an expression that will **evaluate** to true or false, rather than the string "true" or "True" or "TRUE". Therefore, this will work like so:

```
Boolean.parseBoolean("true"); // equals true
Boolean.parseBoolean("1 > 2"); // not the string "true", therefore returns false.
```

Generally speaking, you should be very cautious about dynamic execution of code contained in strings. If the string is being passed in from a user, it's quite dangerous. My advice would be to find a better way.

If you really need to do this:

- One of the other answers mention using `ScriptEngine`. Please be aware that this evaluates the string as **JavaScript**, not as Java. For simple boolean expressions, that's probably fine, but you should be aware of it. JavaScript has rules for truthiness that are perplexing at times, and they will not evaluate the same in Java.

For example, try running this in ScriptEngine:

```
1 > '0' // true in JavaScript, but probably unexpected in your code!
```

- If you want to do this all properly in Java, you could use the [Java Compiler API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html). Unfortunately, it's not as simple as simply feeding expressions as strings to the ScriptEngine. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173294/compiling-fully-in-memory-with-javax-tools-javacompiler) might be useful, however, for in-memory compilation of Java code.