# Create Swing component from string

Tags: java, swing

How can I create a Swing component ( such as a JPanel or JButton ) dynamically from a string that refers a component name?

For example;

```
String c = "JPanel";

(c) com = new (c)(); // It must be equivalent JPanel com = new JPanel();
```

or a function like this;

```
Object c = Object.createObjectFromString(c);
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do this? All the validation you are going to need will just make your code unreadable.

Comment: I suppose this could be done with reflection, but could you give us more context here? Why do you need/want this functionality?

Comment: Well, it can be done with `Class.forName()` and then calling appropriate constructor, but why would you need this ?

Comment: Looks like we're all smelling the same bad code smell here.

Comment: I am smelling, write your own preprocessor for java smell.

Comment: @PrototypeStark: could be, but I'd like to know, because if not, there may be much better ways to solve the overlying problem (whatever that currently  is).

Comment: Using a combination of generics and reflection would probably work.

Comment: @luiscubal: generics? How so?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels a better solution may not necessarily be an easy one. I think he can easily solve that with a preprocessor.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels `public T createObject<T>(Class<T> type) { ... }`, maybe? Or `public T createObject<T>(String typeName)`. Of course, if he really has zero clue of what the type will be then pure reflection would be the only way to go - this smells a lot like dynamic typing.

Comment: @ALL: I have a xml that contains components name and their properties. I read this data and want to render dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done, using the [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html):

```
Class<?> klazz = Class.forName("javax.swing.JPanel");
JPanel panel = (JPanel) klazz.newInstance();
```

Notice that you have to pass a fully-qualified class name to the `forName()` method, and that at some point (be it as a type parameter to `Class<?>` or by using a cast like in the above code) you'll have to explicitly specify the class that you intend to instantiate. Or if you don't care about the exact type of the instance, you can simply do this:

```
Object obj = klazz.newInstance();
```

Also, I'm assuming that the class has defined a no-arguments constructor. If that is not the case, you'll have to create a `Constructor` object first before instantiating the new object:

```
Class<?> klazz = Class.forName("javax.swing.JPanel");
Constructor<?> constructor = klazz.getDeclaredConstructor(/* parameter types */);
JPanel panel = (JPanel) constructor.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use reflection:

```
// c is JPanel for instance
Sting componentClassName = "javax.swing." + c; 
JPanel panel = (JPanel)Class.forName(componentClassName).newInstance();
```

Using `Class.newInstance()` requires a the component you are creating to have a default constructor but this is provided by most if not all the standard Swing components.

Comment: But, I don't know what is it type. It could be JButton

Comment: @miqbal: that's where the String parameter comes in. Use a variable there and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

see here [How to create an object from a string in java how to eval a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168931/how-to-create-an-object-from-a-string-in-java-how-to-eval-a-string) and [Creating an instance from string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767088/creating-an-instance-from-string-in-java). But I would also suggest you to write your own preprocessor if you want it to evaluate in 1 single line. That's what C/C++ preprocessors do.