# How do I add JDK libraries to my app?

Tags: java, android

I understand that Android doesn't use the full jdk, but I want to add javax to my Android project. More specifically I want to add javax.tools. I can't find a download for it though. Do I have to add the entire JDK as an external library to access javax.tools? Or is none of this possible?

Comment: What specifically in `javax.tools` do you need. This is likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javax.\* cannot be imported in my Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803343/javax-cannot-be-imported-in-my-android-app)

Comment: I'm trying to implement this solution on Android https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599427/how-to-compile-and-run-java-source-code-in-memory