# How to create java.lang.reflect.Method using method stored in String

Tags: java, reflection

I want to parse a method stored in a string variable, for example:

```
"public void printStr(String arg) { System.out.println("Method called"); } "
```

and convert this into a java.lang.reflect.Method object.

How can I do this?

Comment: You won't be able to directly convert it into a `Method`. If you want a `Method` then you'll have to compile the source first, which means fully valid Java. Or you could try using the [JShell API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/jdk.jshell/module-summary.html).

Comment: A method needs a class to live in. Is it OK if you include the enclosing class? The method may be static or not

Comment: Hi @Bohemian it is fine if i include method inside enclosing class. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: See [`JavaCompiler`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) and [`ClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html). Also see [How to compile and run java source code in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599427/how-to-compile-and-run-java-source-code-in-memory).

Comment: Build your class def as a string, then compile it in memory and load it using the class loader. I have used Janino with success. Javassist also seems popular.